# Try/catch blocks with asynchronous JavaScript with callback functions

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a piece of code:

```
function backgroundReadFile(url, callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (req.status < 400)
      callback(req.responseText);
  });
  req.send(null);
}
try {
  backgroundReadFile("example/data.txt", function(text) {
    if (text != "expected")
      throw new Error("That was unexpected");
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Hello from the catch block");
}
```

In my console I get

```
Error: That was unexpected (line 13)
```

which is just fine. But, I am told that:

> In the code, the exception will not be caught because the
>   call to `backgroundReadFile` returns immediately. Control then leaves
>   the `try` block, and the function it was given won’t be called until
>   later.

The question is: why other errors will not be caught here? When we have, say, connection problems, or the file does not exist? As far as I can see, the callback function won`t execute if

```
req.addEventListener("load")
```

is not triggered, for example. But it still does - I still get the same error -  `Error: That was unexpected (line 13)`.

What does it mean - "exception will not be caught because the call to `backgroundReadFile` returns immediately"?

Thank you.

Comment: "Told" by whom?

Comment: It is a passage from "Eloquent JavaScript", and the code is also from this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step breakdown of what happens in your code.

1. The code enters the try-catch block.
2. `backgroundReadFile` is called, with two parameters: `"example/data.txt"`, and an anonymous function.
3. `backgroundReadFile` creates an AJAX request and calls `send()`. Here's where the concept of asynchrony comes into play: the actual HTTP request is **not** sent right away, but rather placed in a queue to be executed as soon as the browser has finished running whatever code it is running at the moment (i.e. your try-ctach block).
4. `backgroundReadFile` has thus finished. Execution returns to the try-catch block.
5. No exceptions were encountered, so the catch block is skipped.
6. The code containing the try-catch block has finished execution. **Now** the browser can proceed to execute the first asynchronous operation in the queue, which is your AJAX request.
7. The HTTP request is sent, and once a response is received, the `onload` event handler is triggered -- regardless of what the response was (i.e. success or error).
8. The anonymous function you passed to `backgroundReadFile` is called as part of the `onload` event handler, and throws an `Error`. However, as you can see now, your code is **not** inside the try-catch block any more, so it's not caught.

TL;DR: The function that throws the Error is *defined* inside the try-catch block, but *executed* outside it.

Also, error handling in AJAX requests has two sides: connection errors and server-side errors. Connection errors can be a request timeout or some other random error that may occur while sending the request; these can be handled in the `ontimeout` and `onerror` event handlers, respectively. However, if the HTTP request makes it to the server, and a response is received, then as far as the `XMLHttpRequest` is concerned, the request was successful. It's up to you to check, for example, the `status` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` (which contains the HTTP response code, e.g. 200 for "OK", 404 for "not found", etc.), and decide if it counts as successful or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when exactly the request is sent when making it asynchronously? There is this queue, and in my code the request is sent when the `try/catch` block is over. What about other instances? Will the `send()` be sent when a current function is over, for example? In other words, as far as I see it, everything that is after `send()` and the actual call to the `backgroundReadFile` will be executed first (i.e. prior to the `backgroundReadFile` actual call), when we talk about asynchronous requests?

Comment: It's called the "event loop". Basically, there are three ways javascript code can be started: 1. when the browser processes a `<script>` tag, 2. when an event is triggered, or 3. when you invoke and asynchronous operation. In case 1, javascript will look in the queue after the chunk of code inside the `<script>` tag has finished running. In case 2, it's after the event handler function has returned, and in case 3 it's after the async operation finished. Here's an article from MDN that explains it much better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 2):

Your `backgroundReadFile` function has two parts: A synchronous part, and an asynchronous part:

```
function backgroundReadFile(url, callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();             // Synchronous
  req.open("GET", url, true);                 // Synchronous
  req.addEventListener("load", function() {   // Synchronous
    if (req.status < 400)                     // *A*synchronous
      callback(req.responseText);             // *A*synchronous
  });
  req.send(null);                             // Synchronous
}
```

You're quite right that an error thrown by the *synchronous* part of that function would be caught by your `try`/`catch` around the call to it.

An error in the *asynchronous* part will not by caught by that `try`/`catch`, because as someone told you, by then the flow of control has already moved on.

So it *could* be perfectly reasonable to have a `try`/`catch` around the call to that function, if it may throw from its synchronous code.

---

Side note: If you're going to use the callback style, you should *always* call back so the code using your function knows the process has completed. One style of doing that is to pass an `err` argument to the callback as the first argument, using `null` if there was no error, and then any data as a second argument (this is often called the "Node.js callback style"). But in modern environments, a better option would be to use a `Promise`. You can do that with minimal changes like this:

```
function backgroundReadFile(url) {
  return new Promsie(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.addEventListener("load", function() {
      if (req.status < 400) {
        resolve(req.responseText);
      } else {
        reject(new Error({status: req.status}));
    });
    req.addEventListener("error", reject);
    req.send(null);
  });
}
```

...which you use like this:

```
backgroundReadFile(url)
    .then(function(text) {
        // Use the text
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // Handle error
    });
```

But in the specific case of `XMLHttpRequest`, you could use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead, which already provides you with a promise:

```
function backgroundReadFile(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error({status: response.status});
      }
      return response.text();
  });
}
```